# How can I align Text next to an Image Button inside a vertical Scrollview

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to align some text next to an Imagebutton inside of a vertically oriented Scrollview, but I am out of ideas.

This is an App for my Grandma, to help her understand her phone and the Symbols better.

```
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/Button1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:src="@drawable/SrcBtn1"/>


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:text="Button 1"
                android:textSize="40dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

I can't manage to get the Text next to the Imagebutton

Comment: as in to the right of the button? Change your LinearLayout orientation to horizontal. An image of what you have, and what you want would help. (using screenshots and paint or similar to design it)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to replace `LinearLayout` with `RelativeLayout` which is made just for this!
here are all of its attributes:
[link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html)

look for the `LEFT_OF` and `RIGHT_OF` attributes.

Comment: The text alignment woked great, but how can I put multiple Image Buttons below each other?

Comment: Well, there are a few ways of placing your objects relatively.
One way is relative to the parent with "android:layout_alignParent[Top]" properties.
Second way is placing your object relative to other children with properties like "android:layout_to[RightOf]" or "android:layout_below".

For you, I think "layout_below" will do the trick, if it's only a column of buttons that you want.
In Android development you have many tools and thus many ways to get something done. Choosing the right way depends on the desired outcome.

Comment: If your goal is to get some kind of a table or a scrolling list, I recommand on TableView or ListView.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/Button1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:text="Button 1"
            android:textSize="40dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can use [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout) to make this layout super fast.

**Here us an example layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layoutDirection="ltr"
  android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="some text"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button5"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:text="some text"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button7"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/button6"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button6"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button6" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:text="some text"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button8"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/button6"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button6"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:text="some text"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/button6"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button6"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button7" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".5" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button5"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button6"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button6"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button8"
        android:src="@drawable/wolverine"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button8"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button7"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button7"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        android:src="@drawable/shadow" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button7"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button5"
        android:src="@drawable/rose" />


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

**It will look like this:**

[image]

---

This will work for your Grandmas phone, but please notice that If you want to make a responsive layout using `ConstraintLayout` you will have to avoid using fixed sizes on your views and that's because different phones got different screen size so using fixed size value will not look the same on all devices.

You can use [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout) with [guidelines](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/guidelines.html) and [Chains](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/create_chains.html) to support different screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

To align some text next to an Imagebutton inside of a vertically oriented Scrollview. we can use linear layout with horizontal orientation

**Like This**

```
 <ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/Button1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:src="@drawable/srcbtn1" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:text="Button 1"
            android:textSize="40dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```